# How do I get distinct items from one table into another?

Tags: sql

> **EDIT**: Because I'm using ExactTarget (Salesforce Marketing Cloud), I only have access to the **SELECT** statement.  None of the good SQL that would make this easy.

I have a table of Customers and a table of Coupons.  I'd like to assign unique codes to eligible Customers but I'm a little bit stuck on query #1.  (Query #2 is an easy join.)

**TABLE 1**

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Customer    | CouponType  | CouponCode |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Customer1   | 20pctoff    |            |
| Customer2   | 20pctoff    |            |
| Customer3   | 10pctoff    |            |
| Customer4   | NULL        |            |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

**TABLE 2**

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| CouponType  | CouponCode  | AssignedTo |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 10pctoff    | Coupon1     |            |
| 20pctoff    | Coupon2     |            |
| 30pctoff    | Coupon3     |            |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Query #1 would result in the following:

Customer1 = Coupon2
Customer2 = none (no more 20pctoff available)
Customer3 = Coupon1
Customer4 = none (not eligible)

The second SQL to update table 2 is a simple join (I don't need help with that).

Comment: Customer2 = none (no more 20pctoff available) where is the count of coupons stored ?? or there is only one of each type ??

Comment: Customer2 = none -- because the guy giving me the codes didn't give me enough codes.  I have a separate routine to order more coupons.  Customer2 would get theirs later.

Comment: I feel like I'm going to have to use a 2 temporary tables...  SELECT row_number() as id, customer, coupontype where coupontype = 20pctoff // select row_number() as id, couponcode, coupontype where coupontype = 20pctoff // select t1.customer, t1.coupontype, t2.couponcode from table1 t1 left join on table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

Comment: what would be the fourth entry in table 2 if you had two 20pctoff   coupons ??

Comment: it would be another coupontype / couponcode pair.  (probably '20pctoff' / 'Coupon4').  My table2 example should have been better, sorry.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I suspect it's Microsoft/T-SQL because I've seen other parts of this SaaS platform using ASPX so I think their entire platform is Microsoft-based, but all they expose to us is a webform in which we can type SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a third table.  Inelegant as heck, but that's the price to pay for using ExactTarget sometimes.  Caveat, requires iterating through known CouponCodes 1 at a time.

New table:

```
+-----+------------------+--------------+
| ID  | Customer         | CouponCode   |
+-----+------------------+--------------+
```

> Target table3, overwrite

SELECT row_number() OVER (order by Customer) as ID, Customer from Table1 where CouponType = '20pctoff'

> Target table3, update

SELECT row_number() OVER (order by CouponCode) as ID, CouponCode from Table2 where CouponType = '20pctoff' and AssignedTo is NULL

> Target table1, update

SELECT t3.Customer, t3.CouponCode FROM table3 t3 inner join table1 t1 on t1.Customer = t3.Customer where t3.Customer is not NULL and t3.CouponCode is not NULL

> Target table2, update

SELECT t3.Customer as AssignedTo, t3.CouponCode FROM table3 t3 inner join table2 t2 on t2.CouponCode = t3.CouponCode where t3.Customer is not null and t3.CouponCode is not null